# Different view of SVG circle element in iPad and Windows PC

Tags: html, css, svg

I get different view of SVG ellipse element in iPad and Windows PC: [Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nSuq.jpg)

How can I get **stroke-width:2px;** for all strokes?

```html
<svg width="64px" height="64px"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 58.1 64">
<defs>
 <style>
  .features_ico1{
   fill:none;
   stroke:#7a992b;
   stroke-linecap:round;
   stroke-linejoin:round;
   stroke-width:2px;
  }
 </style>
</defs>
<ellipse class="features_ico1" cx="29.05" cy="12.81" rx="28.05" ry="11.81"/>
<path class="features_ico1" d="M95.84,58.66c0,6.52-12.56,11.81-28,11.81s-28-5.29-28-11.81" transform="translate(-38.74 -34.04)"/>
<path class="features_ico1" d="M95.84,71.95c0,6.52-12.56,11.81-28,11.81s-28-5.29-28-11.81" transform="translate(-38.74 -34.04)"/>
<path class="features_ico1" d="M39.74,46.85V85.23c0,6.52,12.56,11.81,28,11.81s28-5.29,28-11.81V46.85" transform="translate(-38.74 -34.04)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: seems like a bug, perhaps you should report it to apple.